# How to add Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to add Bootstrap to my HTML Page.
I've been trying to search but, I don't get it.
I just wanna know the requirements and the the meta tags that are to be included in this.

```
<html>
<head><title>Cube</title></head>
<body>
    <div class="info">Hello Everyone</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are examples on the bootstrap website.

Comment: *I've been trying to search but...* Well, [you're doing it wrong](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).

Comment: I'd recommend you download the lib and examples from the bootstrap website

Comment: visit this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: "I've been trying to search, but..." usually translates to "I looked for copy-paste code, but I couldn't find it, and I don't want to read documentation because I'm lazy." Documentation is always your friend.

Comment: If you are having trouble even setting up a basic page I would say you need to have a good read of the documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ before rushing in. It will definitely help you in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

By adding the CDN

```
      <html>
        <head>
           <title>Cube</title>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="info">Hello Everyone</div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: How to check if its added?

Comment: @VatsalSharma By copying my example

Comment: This is not even half of what is nessecary. Just use the examples on the bootstrap website.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Well. That was kind of my ironic post by giving Vatsal this basic example. Google is obviously NOT his friend.

Comment: The JavaScript that is included from the Bootstrap CDN need to be accompanied by jQuery, furthermore the website won't be responsive without the meta tags that tell mobiles to allow bootstrap to work it's magic.

Comment: See answer below for full html from the bootstrap website including meta tags and jQuery from CDN. Still would advise @VatsalSharma to have a read of the documentation, definitely will save him time in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

See this page for the example - http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

This code below will give you a basic html page but I would recommend you read the documentation and learn how to only include the components that you need.

If you are only usually a few of the javascript components (or none of them), there is very little point including the full file. The same goes for CSS. You will just be adding unnecessary weight to your page.

For example it is possible to just use the bootstrap grid and no other components if that is all you are needing.

You will want to go through the documentation to learn how to use everything that is built into bootstrap if you are new to it, so it would be a good idea to explore the site before rushing into development.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```